# Parse.com : query with two datetime at different column

Tags: parse-platform

I want to build sync method, both from my local database to parse.com and from parse.com to my local database. For first case ( from local to parse.com, Alhamdulillah my script run well. But for second case, i need query between column last_update and last_sync (i do not use updatedAt caused by i can't control it, so i use last_update).

Please explain me how to get all data if last_update is greaterThan last_sync?

From https://www.parse.com/questions/querying-between-two-dates i got query between two dates, but it's from same column, the value of query is real value. But my case, the value of key = last_update is column name, last_sync.

Thank you...

Comment: Just for information: my local db use postgreSql. and this problem is to sync parse.com data to my postgreSql database. As i said at my comment on first answer, i can't use updatedAt because i can't control it. so i need all data that last_update>last_sync to store to my postgreSql database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a query constraint that compares two columns. You need to change your logic. Why do you store both a last_update and last_sync in a record?

Syncing is a complex subject and you can easily mess up the logic. I don't understand how you can store a last_sync date on every record, as this has to be different for every user. You need to store the last_sync value for each user, and use that to compare against the last_update column on all records.

Comment: it's about syncing parse data and my local data. last_sync is datetime parse data and local data syncing. and last_update is datetime parse.com data updated by user from mobile.

So my admin need manual syncing if there is some update by other user via mobile.

So i need all data that last_update>last_syncing --> that's mean all  data that updated by user via mobile but not yet syncing to my local data..

Comment: If you update a local value (i.e. in userdefaults) or on the admin user profile in parse every time you sync data, then you can use that date to compare with the records. I don't see why you would need separate last_sync dates for every object...

Comment: I think you did not understand what i want. I'll try to explain again, but i'm so sorry for my english.
1. last_sync is column that contains datetime when parse.com data and local data synced. For first time there is no data at parse.com. when first syncing, all my local data will stored at parse.com and that datetime stored as last_sync.
2. My apps will accessed via mobile too (IOS and Android), and local data is mean admin pc. so if mobile user change that data, local data did know it. so i need datatime when data changed and stored as last_update.

Comment: 3. I did not use updatedAt, because i can't control it. my last_sync stored with contains datetime when data stored, but updateAt contains datetime at the end of store data. so last_sync should be more than updatedAt when data synced. but updatedAt give more than last_sync. so it's categorized as not yet synced.
4. so i use last_update to control when mobile user change my data. and my query need all data that last_update is greaterThan last_sync (all data did not synced). 

Thanks...